# Download Windows 10 ISO in parts

Tags: windows-10

How can I download the Windows 10 ISO in parts?

I have a daily bandwidth quota of 2 GB, and would like to download 1 GB of the ISO file every day. The Windows Media Creation Tool does not let me Pause/Resume the download. How can I do this?

Comment: You will need to use another tool to download the ISO directly from Microsoft website and stop it manually after each 1GB. The link provided by Microsoft last for 24 hours. If the tool allows it, you can refresh the download address. This will allow to continue where you stopped the download. I use [Internet download manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html) for some downlaods. Disclaimer: I am just a user, not related to the developers.

Comment: Will your public library, local internet cafe or other service provider allow you to do so? A cooperative library IT tech might even do so for you.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple solutions to this, you can ask someone with unlimited internet
to download it for you, and then put it on google drive or dropbox or any other
famous file sharing applications (that person can split the file in 1 GB chunks using winrar)
Thus you can download it 1 file each day

Typical downloading (either from  browser or a download manager application), can
also be used by you smartly (assuming 12:00 AM is the time when your downloading
limit is reached), so you will have to smartly watch everything, may be start
the downloading around 11:00 AM (depending on your download speed, you can do
before or after that time)... Thus when it reaches near 1 GB, pause the downloading.
Then wait for your time limit so that u get the next 1 GB quota, and then resume
the download

3rd way is to ask someone to download the file, and place it on an FTP server
(any PC can be set as FTP server using any famous FTP application), thus you can
then download easily it 1 GB each day.